# Can I change the position of the Google logo in an MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mkmapview

I am making an app that has an MKMapView. I have a translucent UIToolbar on top of the MKMapView. The problem is that the Google logo is beneath it. Is there a way to show the Google logo above (in Y direction, not Z) the UIToolbar instead of beneath it?
[image: screenie]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can. And it can even get approved by apple too.

See here:
http://nachbaur.com/blog/dealing-with-mkmapviews-google-logo-with-translucent-toolbars

And here:
http://rogchap.com/2011/06/17/mkmapview-moving-the-google-logo/

Comment: Links no longer available

Answer (score 4):

The only way would be changing size of `MKMapView` in the same time with `MKCoordinateSpan` that should compensate the amount of the map occupied by `UIToolbar`.  If you goal is to be able to display some portion of the map beneath the toolbar, it is not feasible.

Comment: @MaciejSwic Yes,I know. I can read too. I wouldn't do it that way. Apple may change the internal structure of MKMapView without any disclosure and your app will crash. I suggested a more complex solution that is somewhat safe

Comment: How does looping through a views subviews and verifying the class crash an app? If the image view goes away as it did with Apple maps, the method described on nachbaur.com will return nil. As we all know sending messages to nil does nothing, no crash.

Comment: @MaciejSwic It won't crash. There is no Google logo anymore.

Comment: Well, no, but there is a "Legal" link that must remain visible. See https://gist.github.com/maciekish/5947238

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, worrying if it might violate terms of use. As @Black Frog recommended, you should move toolbar or resize the mapView to show Google logo. Though it makes translucent toolbar to be meaningless, it's better than making your app to be potentially rejected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Google API to move the logo.  You will need to move your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky, but it is possible. Enlarge the MKMapView.frame, so the Google logo is hidden. Apple would reject your App, so you need to add the logo again. This can be done with a png of the logo (pm me, I can send it to you). You can place this png wherever you want on the map, Apple accepts.